# How can use a differently named JPA Config instead of "default"?

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I have setup a config called "staging" - in my application.conf along the lines of this:

```
jpa.staging=oraclePersistenceUnitStaging
db.staging.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
db.staging.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
db.staging.user=udrtnsm
db.staging.password="kldj90fdkl"
db.staging.jndiName=OracleDSStaging
```

Evolutions sets up a connection and applies scripts, but the first request from the application shows:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: No JPA     EntityManagerFactory configured for name [default]]]
at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT]
at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT]
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at   play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No JPA EntityManagerFactory configured for name [default]
at play.db.jpa.JPA.em(JPA.java:34) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransactionAsync(JPA.java:169) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.call(TransactionalAction.java:15) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT]
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT]
at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT]
```

Why is it still trying to connect to "**default**"?
Even though I don't have a default in my conf file?
And even though it is finding an connecting to the data source to apply evolutions?